# how to use ajax to update this page?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

hi so i managed to figure out my biggest problem and i am happy its pretty much working the way i want. Now the second stage to reach my goal is for me to be able to update the page without a refresh using ajax. The php etc is below, can someone show me or point me in the right direction. Thanks .

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later';
    exit;   
}
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, "database");

//check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
if (!isset($_GET['feedback']) or !is_numeric($_GET['feedback'])) {
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $feedback = 0;
//otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
  $feedback = (int)$_GET['feedback'];
}
$prev = $feedback - 4;

$query = "SELECT * FROM clients, orders WHERE clients.ID = orders.ID ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT $feedback,4";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);


?>
<div class="sidebar">
           <div class="clientwrapper">
                <h2>Client Feedback</h2>
                    <div class="box">                   
                    <?php 
                     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                     echo '<p> '.$row["Comments"].' <span class="name"> By '.$row["Organisation"].' </span></p>'; 
                     }
                     ?>
                    <?php echo  '<a class="nodecoration" href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?feedback='.($feedback+4).'" ><span class="next-button">More</span></a>' ?>
                    <?php if ($prev >= 0) echo  '<a class="nodecoration" href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?feedback='.$prev.'" ><span class="prev-button"></span></a>' ?>

                   <div class="clear"></div>
                     </div>
            </div>



         <div class="announcewrapper">
        <h2>Announcements</h2>
        <div class="box">
        <p>There are currently no announcements.</p>
        </div>       
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: hi, first of all its not php query,Its MySQL query.:) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, as I am not working on your code, and I normally develop by tweaking the code (and testing it) step by step. So this may need a bit more work on your end to get it to behave properly...

```
// BUGGY INITIAL CODE REMOVED
```

**Appendum**

This solution uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [`$.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load) - See http://api.jquery.com/load.
You will need to include jQuery in the `<head>` section of the page the above code will be within, using the following:

```
<head>
<!-- Whatever other bits are already here //-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**Appendum #2**

The following is a self-contained PHP Script which demonstrates this functionality. Has been tested and works. Simply remove the lines marked "TEST DATA ONLY" and remove the `#`s from the beginnings of lines marked "PROD DATA" and it should be halfway to a complete solution for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tester</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
a.inactive { color:#AAA; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
# Page Configuration Details
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root' ;
$dbPass = 'password';
$dbBase = 'database';
$reviewsPerPage = 4;

#$link = mysqli_connect( $dbHost , $dbUser , $dbPass , $dbBase );         // PROD DATA ONLY
#if( mysqli_connect_errno() )                                             // PROD DATA ONLY
#  die( 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later' ); // PROD DATA ONLY

#$db = mysqli_select_db( $link , $dbBase );                               // PROD DATA ONLY

//check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
if( !isset( $_GET['feedback'] ) || !is_numeric( $_GET['feedback'] ) ){
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $feedback = 0;
  $prevPage = false;
}else{
  //otherwise we take the value from the URL
  $feedback = (int) $_GET['feedback'];
  $prevPage = max( $feedback-$reviewsPerPage , 0 );
}
$nextPage = $reviewsPerPage+$feedback;

#$query = "SELECT * FROM clients, orders                                  // PROD DATA ONLY
#           WHERE clients.ID = orders.ID                                  // PROD DATA ONLY
#           ORDER BY Date DESC                                            // PROD DATA ONLY
#           LIMIT $feedback,$reviewsPerPage";                             // PROD DATA ONLY

#$result = mysqli_query( $link , $query );                                // PROD DATA ONLY

$result = array_fill(                                                     // TEST DATA ONLY
            $feedback ,                                                   // TEST DATA ONLY
            $reviewsPerPage ,                                             // TEST DATA ONLY
            array(                                                        // TEST DATA ONLY
              'Comments'=>'The comments' ,                                // TEST DATA ONLY
              'Organisation'=>'John Smith'                                // TEST DATA ONLY
            )                                                             // TEST DATA ONLY
          );                                                              // TEST DATA ONLY

?>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="clientwrapper">
    <h2>Client Feedback</h2>
    <div id="clientFeedback" class="box">
      <div class="feedbackHolder">
        <div id="clientFeedbackContent">
<?php 
#while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){                           // PROD DATA ONLY
foreach( $result as $k => $row ){                                         // TEST DATA ONLY
  #echo '          <p>'.$row['Comments'].                                 // PROD DATA ONLY
  #     ' <span class="name">By '.$row['Organisation'].'</span></p>';     // PROD DATA ONLY
  echo '          <p>#'.$k.': '.$row['Comments'].                         // TEST DATA ONLY
        ' <span class="name">By '.$row['Organisation'].'</span></p>';     // TEST DATA ONLY
}

echo '          <a class="nodecoration" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?feedback='.$nextPage.'" ><span class="next-button">More</span></a>'."\n";
echo '          <a class="nodecoration'.( $prevPage===false ? ' inactive' : '' ).'" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?feedback='.(int) $prevPage.'" ><span class="prev-button">Prev</span></a>'."\n";
?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var reviewsPerPage = <?php echo $reviewsPerPage; ?>;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        // Bind our Custom Code to the "A" tags with class "nodecoration" within the "clientFeedback" div
        $( '#clientFeedback a.nodecoration' ).live( 'click' , function(e){
          console.log( 'Running' );
          e.preventDefault();
          // Get the URL to Load
          theURL = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
          // Use the jQuery $.load() function to replace the contents of this element
          // with another element gained through AJAX
          $( '#clientFeedback .feedbackHolder' )
            .load(
              theURL+' #clientFeedbackContent' ,
              function(){
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from behaving like it normally would.
              });
        });
      });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="announcewrapper">
    <h2>Announcements</h2>
    <div class="box">
      <p>There are currently no announcements.</p>
    </div>       
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thanks so much, but i have a number of questions. The script as far as i can see doesnt make use of the XMLHTTPRequest to update the div on the fly. Also when clicking on more the page does in fact refresh as it jumps to the top again (or am i mistaken). Lastly i am slightly confused with the javascript portion of the code as it is probably done in a manner that a very experienced person would, and i am only a beginner.

Comment: The XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX Request) is handled by jQuery's `$.load()` function. You will, of course, need to include jQuery in the `<script...</script>` tags at the top of any page you do this on. See http://jquery.com/ for details. (The lack of jQuery in your current page is probably the reason why the links are jumping to a new page.)

Comment: See my Answer - Revised with more detail, references and an example which should give you a better idea of how it works. (Tested OK on XAMPP here.)

Comment: OMG thank you so much i am now able to adapt this on my other pages needing a similar things run THANKS so much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code, it suggests that you're developing a larger application. First, read up on [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). Learning this rather than using old scripting methods will help you *tremendously* in the long run. The benefits of spending the time to do this now *far* outweigh the downside of not getting it working quite as quickly as you may want to.

Having said that, whether or not you decide to class'ify this, I'd rip out the logic in the top part of your script and stick it in another file, accessible from your web server. Rather than echo out table-formatted data, dump out JSON-formatted content.

Replace the top code in this page to `curl` wherever you stick the newly created file on your server and `json_decode` it to get an iterate-able object that you can use to construct your table. If you're dealing with a post-back, then do a `POST` (or better `DELETE`) `curl`.

Now comes the tricky(ish) part. You want your script to *enhance* your server-driven functionality and not be obtrusive. Easiest way is to use a framework like `jQuery`, binding to click events and using `event.preventDefault()` functionality to prevent the server post-back. Within the function that your scripted event is bound to, make your `$.ajax` call there, displaying whatever data you want to in the continuation.

Hope that helps. If you're unfamiliar with any of the terms, a quick google search will yield a ton of documentation on each subject.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but im sorry to say i am an utter noob and dont understand the json and curl stuff (will look at later). This is not a large project, the wesite only has approx 12 pages with a comment box being repeated via includes on various pages. I plan on placing the top code in another file as config and query file and just include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code for AJAX,

```
function change_category(id)
{

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_update_query.php?subcat="+sub_cat,
            data:   "pid=" + id,
            success: function(html){
                $("#response_sub_cat").html(html);
            }
        });
}
```

you can put this function on whatever event you are using, i means onClick,onChange etc..
And in ajax_update_query.php page having you query for updating database based on your requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: i had not giving the complete solution with output.its just hint what i was given.."A discerning eye needs only a hint, and understatement leaves the imagination free to build its own elaborations."  Thanks.